# Create and used StaticResource Path in XAML code

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, content

Доброго времени суток.

Как можно заставить работать следующий код в XAML

```
<Path x:Key="ArrowUp" Data="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" Fill="Gold"/>

<RepeatButton Content="{StaticResource ArrowUp}"/>
```

Также, я пробовал так:

```
<Style x:Key="ArrowUp" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gold"/>
</Style>

<RepeatButton Content="{StaticResource ArrowUp}"/>
```

Но похоже это не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, нужно задать шаблон ContentTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ArrowUp" >
     <Path Data="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" Fill="Gold"/>
</DataTemplate>

<RepeatButton ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ArrowUp}">
```